# Is it correct to say "the child was so into the game that he forgot to do things"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I remembered I asked this question before but I couldn't find it.

A child is playing a game and he liked it so much that he forgot to go for a pee and he peed his pants.

I remembered "**Kate Bunting**" gave me a good phrase for it.

**What should we say when a child focuses on something too much that he forget other things**?

Is it natural to say these?

"**the child was so into the game that he forgot to do ...**"

"**the child was so immersed in the game that he forgot to do...**"

"**the child was so occupied in the game that he forgot to do...**"

"**Kate Bunting**" said something else, not these above words.

Comment: Are you asking us to proofread your sentences, or is there one particular aspect of English you'd like help with? Your use of "so ... that ... forgot" is correct

Comment: @gotube, I asked this question before, but I couldn't find it

Comment: @gotube, "**Kate Bunting**"  used some words that I could not remember what they are.

Comment: I really don't know what you're asking for. Do you want a phrase that means the same as forget?

Comment: @gotube, what should we say when a child focuses on something too much that he forget other things

Comment: He's distracted? engrossed? absorbed? caught up?

Comment: @gotube, yes engrossed is I m looking for

Comment: I really can't remember what synonym I might have suggested. _Engrossed_ sounds quite plausible. _Into something_ is more slangy than the others.